# Enum parameter for function

Tags: swift

```
enum FooEnum: Int {
    case fooEnumCase = 13512
    case fooEnumCase2 = 425156
}

class FooClass {
    public func myFunction(chosenEnumCase: fooEnum) -> String {
        /* Logic */
    }
}

fooClass.myFunction(fooEnum.fooEnumCase)
```

---

I am getting the error:

> `FooEnum` is not convertible to `FooClass`

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: *Hint:* `myFunction` is an *instance method,* it is called on an *instance* of `fooClass`, not on the class itself.

Comment: Not necessarily the cause of your problem, but type names in swift should start with an uppercased letter.

Comment: @MartinR yea didn't really realize that until a minute ago

Comment: Try `fooClass().myFunction(fooEnum.fooEnumCase)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the code is very hard to read with lowercase class names.

Two issues:

With this syntax the method is supposed to be a **class** function.

```
public static func myFunction(chosenEnumCase: FooEnum) -> String
```

Which raises a new error

> Missing argument label 'chosenEnumCase:' in call

and you have to add the parameter label:

---

```
enum FooEnum: Int {
    case fooEnumCase = 13512
    case fooEnumCase2 = 425156
}

class FooClass {
    public static func myFunction(chosenEnumCase: FooEnum) -> String {
        //logic
    }
}

FooClass.myFunction(chosenEnumCase: FooEnum.fooEnumCase)
```

Answer (score 1):

To explain the error message let's consider `fooClass.myFunction`:

```
let f: (fooClass) -> ((fooEnum) -> String) = fooClass.myFunction
```

It's a function that expects an instance of `fooClass`, and returns another function `((fooEnum) -> String)`. Whereas in your code it is fed an instance of type `fooEnum`.

---

Call that function on a instance:

```
let myInstance = fooClass()
myInstance.myFunction(chosenEnumCase: fooEnum.fooEnumCase)
```

Or make `myFunction` a class function:

```
public class func myFunction(chosenEnumCase: fooEnum) -> String
```

---

PS: To conform to the Swift naming conventions use `FooEnum` and `FooClass`.

Comment: *Challenge:* Explain the compiler error “'fooEnum' is not convertible to 'fooClass'” :)

Comment: @MartinR Do I get a prize if the challenge is met? 

Comment: @Carpsen90 I don't get it ... `let f: (fooClass) -> ((fooEnum) -> String) = fooClass.myFunction` isn't same as my code

Comment: @john in your code you are passing `fooEnum.fooEnumCase` to the function `fooClass.myFunction`.

Comment: @Carpsen90: You get my +1 :) – Btw, the underlying reason is that [Instance Methods are “Curried” Functions in Swift](https://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-instance-methods-curried-functions/)

Comment: @MartinR What an honor 

Comment: @Carpsen90 sorry to bother but I still don't understand why this is happening

Comment: @john Your code is equivalent to `let f = fooClass.myFunction; f(fooEnum.fooEnumCase)`. Do read the article provided in the previous comments.